# Transfer or Dump from Azure MS SQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, azure, dump

I am trying to transfer a Microsoft SQL Server database stored on Azure to a different database (e.g. MySQL, Postgres) to access it locally on a Macbook.

I have tried various methods with no success. Does anyone know a sure-fire way to transfer or dump this type of database?

Answer (score -1):

Op didn't specify a budget.

> sure-fire way

I get that you said a different database(s), however you didn't explicitly say you did not want to xfer to SQL Server, and it occurs to me perhaps you were not aware you could xfer to SQL Server on Mac.

Buy VMWare's Fusion, install Windows OS in the VM on your Mac; install SQL Server on the Windows VM, backup and restore to your local hard drive.

**Warning**

> backup and restore to your local hard drive.

This can be easier said than done, you might do some research on this aspect prior to making any purchases.